# Would I be able to run a game server on a tablet?

Tags: tablet, gaming

I want to run a small Garry's Mod server (<8 players) with SRCDS over wifi. What difficulties would I encounter if I were to run a game server on a tablet with a 1.2GHz processor and 512MB of ram? ([example tablet](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/8GB-New-7-Google-Android-4-0-Capacitive-512MB-Mid-Tablet-WiFi-A13-3G-Flash-11-1-/190738056196?pt=US_Tablets&hash=item2c68dfc404&_uhb=1)).

If I can't find a way to run SRCDS (which has a CLI) on android with root access then I would assume I could install a linux distribution on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a major issue here - most of valve's software runs on x86 systems as opposed to arm. Even if you could get a full fat linux distro on the tablet, its unlikely to be able to run software for another architecture.

Comment: Damn, but thanks for the info. It looks like pretty much any system <$100 has an ARM processor. Although I'm marking the question as answered I'm still going to look for a cheap system that can run SRCDS.

Comment: @mcjohnalds45 If it doesn't need to be portable just get an old desktop. You should be able to get one for less than 100.

Comment: Well "no" is an answer here. I'd say an old laptop or desktop is the best bet here, though there's some small AMD and via x86 boards in the 200-300 USD range

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, but wi-fi is probably not the best way to connect, why not do something similar with a raspberry pi, or some of the other stick computers? A touchscreen is not exactly necessary..